# PHP regex preg_match numbers before a multiword string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract the number 203 from this sample.

Here is the sample I am running the regex against:

```
<span class="crAvgStars" style="white-space:no-wrap;"><span class="asinReviewsSummary" name="B00KFQ04CI" ref="cm_cr_if_acr_cm_cr_acr_pop_" getargs="{&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;linkCode&quot;:&quot;sp1&quot;}">

<a href="https://www.amazon.com/Moto-1st-Gen-Screen-Protector/product-reviews/B00KFQ04CI/ref=cm_cr_if_acr_cm_cr_acr_img/181-2284807-1957201?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sp1&showViewpoints=1" target="_top"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/customer-reviews/ratings/stars-4-5._CB192238104_.gif" width="55" alt="4.3 out of 5 stars" align="absbottom" title="4.3 out of 5 stars" height="12" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;</span>(<a href="https://www.amazon.com/Moto-1st-Gen-Screen-Protector/product-reviews/B00KFQ04CI/ref=cm_cr_if_acr_cm_cr_acr_txt/181-2284807-1957201?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sp1&showViewpoints" target="_top">203 customer reviews</a>)</span>
```

Here is the code I am using that does not work

```
preg_match('/^\D*(\d+)customer reviews.*$/',$results[0], $clean_results);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $clean_results);
echo "</pre>";
//expecting 203
```

It is just returning

```
<pre>array ()</pre>
```

Comment: `'/(\d+) customer reviews\b/'`

Comment: The result of `preg_match` is an array, so to print it you have to use `print_r`, not `echo`. The first parenthesis group is in `$clean_results[1]`

Comment: Awesome! This is the answer. I'm happy to mark this! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @fusion3k He's using `print_r`. It's showing an empty array.

Comment: Does a faster operation then preg_match exist? Thanks @fusion3k I will be storing it via     $clean_results[1]

Comment: @Barmar yes, I see now. I have read `echo.. //expecting`. BTW, the OP agree (??? LOL)

Comment: @fusion3k I tested it as print_r( $clean_results[1]); and it worked.

Comment: @user1669039 Fine! We don't understand why `print_r( $clean_results )` output empty array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp has two problems.

First, there are other numbers in the string before the number of customer reviews (like `4.3 out of 5 stars` and `height="12"`), but `\D*` prevents matching that -- it only matches if there are no digits anywhere between the beginning of the string and the number of reviews.

Second, you have no space between `(\d+)` and `customer reviews`, but the input string has a space there.

There's no need to match any of the string before and after the part that contains the number of customer reviews, just match the part you care about.

```
preg_match('/(\d+) customer reviews/',$results[0], $clean_results);
$num_reviews = $clean_results[1];
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FxyXHA)